# Is this a held ball (which should have led to a jump ball)?

Tags: rules, basketball, nba

Please see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxY47I-pc-Q

Greg Anthony (the commentator) is quite insistent that this should have been a jump ball.  But it looks to me that the ball was not in Hibbert's "continuous possession" (as required by the rules, see below).

Instead, it looks like Hibbert went up, Millsap blocked it, ball completely left Hibbert's hands, Hibbert rebounded the blocked shot (albeit while still in the air), and came back down with it (just like you would when getting any rebound). So this shouldn't be a jump ball (and the officials got it right with their no-call). Is my interpretation of the rules correct?

> A held ball occurs when two opponents have one or both hands firmly
>   on the ball or anytime a defensive player touches the ball causing the
>   offensive player to return to the floor with the ball in his
>   continuous possession. ([p. 19 of this PDF](http://mediacentral.nba.com/media/mediacentral/Official-NBA-Rule-Book.pdf))

Comment: Im wondering if Greg doesn't have an angle there to see that Hibbert released the ball before coming back down.

Comment: Yes but he was continuing to say the same thing even as he (and the viewers) were looking at the replay, where we could clearly see that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes your interpretation of the rules is correct. The commentators get real decisive one way or another. They will argue something and not always be right. They do it so people will watch them because they actually get into the game. I dislike the commentators that just say "He shot the ball" or "Did you see that pass?" And they have no real excitement behind it.